# Image not showing on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kineticjs

I'm making a webpage and after tweaking some code my image on the website doesn't show anymore but i have errors in the console here is the code please someone help ive tried a few things to no luck so this my last resort

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>        
    <head>
        <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css">
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="kinetic-v5.1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="easy-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse easy-sidebar" style="z-index: 99999; position: absolute;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle easy-sidebar-toggle" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <aside>
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                            <li><a href="#one" aria-controls="one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">One</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#two" aria-controls="two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Two</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="one"></div>
                            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="two"></div>
                        </div>
                    </aside>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                            </li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="bodyMain" style="z-index: 1 !important; display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 0px;">
            <div class="container" style="">
                <button class="btn btn-danger easy-sidebar-toggle">Toggle Sidebar</button>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                </script>
            </div>
            <div id="canvasContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 940px; border: 1px solid; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; "></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
                        setYPos(delta);
                    });

                });


                var yposition = 50;
                var xposition = 20;
                var width = 200;
                var height = 137;

                function setYPos(v) {
                    yposition += v;
                    width += v;
                    height += v;
                    console.debug('Y: ', yposition);
                    drawImage(imageObj);
                }

                function drawImage(imageObj) {

                    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                        container: "canvasContainer",
                        width: $('#canvasContainer').width(),
                        height: $('#canvasContainer').height()
                    });

                    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

                    // image

                    var image1 = new Kinetic.Image({
                        image: imageObj,
                        x: xposition,
                        y: yposition,
                        width: width,
                        height: height,
                        draggable: true,
                        dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
                            if (pos.x < this.minX) this.minX = pos.x;
                            return {
                                x: pos.x,
                                y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
                        xposition = stage.getPointerPosition().x;
                    });

                    // add cursor styling
                    image1.on('mouseover', function() {
                        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                    });
                    image1.on('mouseout', function() {
                        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                    });

                    image1.dragBoundFunc(function() {
                        return {
                            x: xposition,
                            y: yposition
                        };
                    });

                    layer.add(image1);
                    stage.add(layer);



                    var imageObj = new Image();
                    imageObj.onload = function() {
                        drawImage(this);
                    };

                    imageObj.src = 'image1.png';

                };
            </script>
        </div>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is because you are defining the `imageObj` variable after it is being used. Instead, rearrange your code to put the `imageObj` definition near the other top level variable definitions.

In other words, change the big script block to something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            setYPos(delta);
        });

    });


    var yposition = 50;
    var xposition = 20;
    var width = 200;
    var height = 137;

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawImage(this);
    };

    imageObj.src = 'image1.png';

    function setYPos(v) {
        yposition += v;
        width += v;
        height += v;
        console.debug('Y: ', yposition);
        drawImage(imageObj);
    }

    function drawImage(imageObj) {

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: "canvasContainer",
            width: $('#canvasContainer').width(),
            height: $('#canvasContainer').height()
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        // image

        var image1 = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: imageObj,
            x: xposition,
            y: yposition,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            draggable: true,
            dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
                if (pos.x < this.minX) this.minX = pos.x;
                return {
                    x: pos.x,
                    y: this.getAbsolutePosition().y
                }

            }
        });

        stage.getContent().addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
            xposition = stage.getPointerPosition().x;
        });

        // add cursor styling
        image1.on('mouseover', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        });
        image1.on('mouseout', function() {
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        });

        image1.dragBoundFunc(function() {
            return {
                x: xposition,
                y: yposition
            };
        });

        layer.add(image1);
        stage.add(layer);
    };
</script>
```